# Build a new hash, by iterating over a nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

So i am trying to re-organise some data from the Google Places API, currently it comes out of their API like this:

```
{"results"=> [
             {"geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>51.503815, "lng"=>-0.11007}}, "icon"=>"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png", "id"=>"5f212d158f4181db3ac0619fb3c52f36d4e276c2", "name"=>"Madeira Cafe", "reference"=>"CnRjAAAApaZWmTl5wOMtW49q3D1BLKAJ_M8lmZxaD6_-AU92qWfVZdokfTWOzlp5En_r9hSUHx-EeP71hzH7iDPYAGPtiqEAXvT4WcI3xlc5XUivenbQLw0j5MHW-ErL-Hbk4xB_by0OSsXCz9etNgkjbp0QCRIQ82Dgj-I3DAJqr7I3EwsFEhoUm2RXf2rCFlSuhfKjSsPuWKA2VGA",     {"results"=> [{"geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>51.503815, "lng"=>-0.11007}},
              "icon"=>"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
              "id"=>"11111111",
              "name"=>"Madeira Cafe",
              "reference"=>"xxxxx",
              "types"=>["restaurant", "food", "establishment"],
              "vicinity"=>"London"}]}
```

The results get put into a hash with one key value  - `"results"`

The rest of the data is the nested inside (i think) with `"geometry"` being the first of each record.

What I am trying to get to is a neat Hash that has one ID per place, with Lat / Lng and Name stored... so it can be stored and queried.

I have tried something like this:

```
results_hash = {}
result.each do |geometry, location, id|
  results_hash[id] = geometry
end

p results_hash
```

but I can't get it to work... it always outputs nil or just the same hash?

I hope this makes sense, as usual if someone just says "read this" its still a great help.

Thanks!

Charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
results_hash = result["results"].inject({}) { |h, res| h[res["id"]] = res["geometry"]; h }
```

This gives you the following hash (printed with `awesome_print`):

```
{
    "2d48a3306535b60663645323cdf972c320da8b9d" => {
        "location" => {
            "lng" => -0.114522,
            "lat" => 51.502653
        }
    },
    "5f212d158f4181db3ac0619fb3c52f36d4e276c2" => {
        "location" => {
            "lng" => -0.11007,
            "lat" => 51.503815
        }
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to format it slightly nicer:

```
results_hash = result["results"].inject({}) do |h, res| 
  h[res["id"]] = res["geometry"]
  h
end
```

Or if you are using 1.9:

```
results_hash = result["results"].each_with_object({}) do |res, h| 
  h[res["id"]] = res["geometry"]
end
```

Comment: hey thanks! can you think of any reason why I am getting this as an error? I think it might be my console cause I just got an "each" error on some other code...
`<main>': undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Charlie: Did it work? If yes, can you please upvote and/or accept this answer so other know that this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi, at the moment when I use this solution it gives the results like this "21321" => {"name" => test, "lat" => 223123, "lng" => 221312} how do I bring the first bit inside the {} so it has id => 2211?  If I do it using the example above it only produces one result,,, i guess because it is not iterating over anything?

Comment: @Charlie Davis: what do you want as the key then?

Comment: sorry I was offline yesterday, what I am trying to get to is {"id":132312321, "lat": 23.232323, "lng":-0.22222} I am converting it to json format using .to_json but need everything insdie the brackets for the API i am using

Comment: I have done this now, I used this syntax:result_hash2 << 
    {:id => result[:id], :lat => result[:geometry][:coordinates].last, :lng => result[:geometry][:coordinates].first}

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of hashes, i.e. [{:geometry => ..., :id => ...}, {:geometry => ..., :id => ...}, etc]. I would extract the array, then iterate over each element in the array (i.e. each element in the array is a hash) using the [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) method and build a new hash as you go.

Something to the extent of:

```
# locations_array is [{"geometry"=>..., "icon"=>..., "id"=>..., etc}, {"geometry"=>..., "icon"=>..., "id"=>..., etc}, etc]
results_hash = locations_array.inject({}) do |hash, element|
  # extract the id key and the long/lat values
  # store them in the new hash
  hash[element[:id]] = element[:geometry]
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hash of places with an ID pointing at lat, lon, and name, you could do something like this:

```
result_hash = {}
hash_from_google["results"].each do |result|
  result_hash[result["id"]] = {
    :name => result["name"], 
    :latitude => result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
    :longitude => result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
  }
end
```

Now you'll have a result that looks something like this:

```
result_hash["5f212..."] => {:name => "Madeira Cafe", :latitude => 51...., :longitude => -0.1....}
```

Essentially, just parse out what you need from the hash you get from the Google Places API.  If you're having issues figuring out how the data is set up or anything like that, try copying it into IRB and playing around with it - doing something like that makes it very easy to figure out the structure of the hash.

Comment: seem to be getting a  can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
error on that one, bit weird

Comment: Where specifically are you getting that error?  If I copy in the hash you get from google (and call it "hash_from_google") and run my code verbatim, I get a result of the form I showed afterwards...

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) 
from the .each do - which is weird, and do is universal method?!

Comment: In that case then `hash_from_google` is nil or `hash_from_google["results"]` is nil.  Make sure to modify the code so that `hash_from_google` gets set to whatever the **full** result from Google Places API is called. (i.e., `hash_from_google = {"results" => [{"geometry" => ...... }`)

Comment: oh my god! please ignore me I am so stupid I had it pointing at the wrong thing! time for a break! and thanks!!